# Is it possible to add hyperlink to WPF Window title?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am just wondering if it is possible to add hyperlink to WPF window title and if it is possible what is the best way of doing that.

I want to have title like that:

**Program name, Version** and that link to my site (e.g **http://mysite.com**)

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea to me. Nobody expects hyperlinks there.

Comment: When you make it work, can you post an example screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't supported out-of-the-box.

However, you can use Control Template to achive this or create an entire custom window of your own.

you can create a control template for your window. Something like that :

```
   <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://mysite.com">
                    My Program, version 1
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>

            <!-- Implement your own control box control -->

            <ContentPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Template>
```

You'll also have to set the window's Style to `None` as follows:

```
 WindowStyle="None"
```

This will also mean that you'll have to implement your own controlBox with minimize, maximize and close buttons.

Check out this links for further information:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Good luck